# Jobs with Resque gives "Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, resque

I followed the tutorial at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/queuing-ruby-resque to queue and run background jobs in a Rails app. After queueing the jobs, it doesn't seem to run any of the jobs since in the console I can see the job has not been processed

```
>Resque.info
=> {:pending=>1, :processed=>0, :queues=>1, :workers=>0, :working=>0, :failed=>0, :servers=>["redis://dory.redistogo.com:9826/0"], :environment=>"production"}
```

If I try to do (locally)

```
bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'jobs:work'
```

On heroku, if I try

```
heroku run rake jobs:work
```

I again get `Don't know how to build task'

In my Rakefile, I have `require 'resque/tasks'` and in my Procfile I have

```
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake jobs:work
resque: env TERM_CHILD=1 bundle exec rake jobs:work
```

I have the Resque and redis gems in my Gemfile, but not delayed_job.

**Update:**
Here is my Rakefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env rake
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
Guard::Application.load_tasks
```

`/lib/tasks` is empty. I have a worker in app/workers that I am enqueueing in a controller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Heroku, if it doesn't work locally.  You'll have to reveal some of your source to help people help you.  For example, what's your Rakefile look like?  The demo app in that article [defines one with a Rake task](https://github.com/trineo/resque-example/blob/master/Rakefile) with the task.  Have you defined your rake task and added the appropriate gem references?

Comment: I think you're right, I'm probably missing something. I have added my Rakefile. I'll look around for resque docs. Let me know which other information I can provide.

Comment: Ohh, I probably need to add the file lib/tasks/resque.rake with `require "resque/tasks"

task "resque:setup" => :environment`. I'll try it when I'm back on my computer.

Comment: Yes, I had to define the task in lib/tasks

Comment: You should also add a: 
task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'
end

so it processes the queue ok

Answer (score 1):

Try `resque:work` instead of `jobs:work` and see if that beings the desired results.

Comment: Gives the same error: `Don't know how to build task 'resque:work'`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `require 'resque/tasks'` in your `Rakefile`, then on the command line:

```
QUEUE=file_serve rake environment resque:work
```

Where `file_serve` is the name of your job (the class would be `FileServeJob`).

See the docs [here](https://github.com/resque/resque#workers) - I found them slightly confusing since the setup and run info comes after the job class creation.

Comment: Note you can also use the wildcard `*` in place of the job name `file_serve` to run all jobs - I had trouble when using a name for some reason.